# Seeking Android library to run Dijkstra on shapefile?

Tags: android

I have a shapefile and I want to find the best way of using Dijkstra on Android platform.

Is there any library that I can use it?

I have to convert it to graphs and then run algorithm. I am confused how make things together for this purpose. If it is possible please suggest some libraries that I can use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean Dijkstra: Spatialite has been [ported to android](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=splite-android). It includes implimentation of [Dijkstra's](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/dijkstra.html) Algorithm, and the A* Algorithm. It may help to familiarise yourself with the [spatialite routing gui](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0/Using-Routing.pdf) before you start trying to write routing queries in your android application.